# Как проще всего добавить на форму WindowsForms круг, цвет которого можно программно менять?

Tags: c#, winforms, gui

Нужно добавить на форму круг, цвет которого можно переключать программно (зелёный, желтый, красный).

Можно сделать три pictureBox'а и из них каждый раз оставлять один видимый, но таких кружков требуется три штуки. Такое решение звучит как-то угловато. Может есть более элегантное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге, нашел самый простой способ. В Visual Studio добавляем в ресурсы картинки с кругами нужных цветов, на форму добавляете picturebox и затем в программе:

```
picturebox.Image = project.Properties.Resources.imgName
```

В большинстве случаев, этот способ должен быть лучшим.

Answer (score 3):

Удобнее всего сделать повторно используемый пользовательский контрол:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public sealed class CircleControl : Control
{
    public CircleControl()
    {
        Height = Width = 100;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var grfx = e.Graphics;
        grfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        grfx.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color), 0, 0, Width-1, Height-1);
        //grfx.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(color), 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1); // рисует закрашенный круг
    }

    private Color color = Color.Black;

    public Color Color
    {
        get
        {
            return color;
        }
        set
        {
            color = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Через свойство `Color` можно задавать цвет окружности. При смене цвета окружность будет перерисована.

Вы можете рисовать в методе `OnPaint` разными способами:
`DrawEllipse` - окружность.
`FillEllipse` - закрашенный круг.

Добавить контрол на форму можно через дизайнер или в конструкторе:

```
var сircleControl = new CircleControl();
сircleControl.Color = Color.Red; // меняем цвет окружности
Controls.Add(сircleControl);
```

**Обновление**

По умолчанию форма контрола будет прямоугольная и при размещении над другими контролами будут видны края. Чтобы избежать этого эффекта нужно добавить следующий код:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);

    var rect = ClientRectangle;
    rect.Inflate(-2, -2);
    var path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddEllipse(rect);
    Region = new Region(path);
}
```

Comment: А можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы этот круг отображался поверх pictureBox? А то получается, что он выводится сзади и закрывается.

Comment: Попробуйте его добавить поверх pictureBox.

Comment: Но как это сделать? Добавляю сразу после InitializeComponent(); в методе формы.

Comment: Первый добавленный контрол в Controls будет выше. Следовательно вам нужно добавить код  раньше других.

Comment: @InfernumDeus Добавил обновление в ответ. Думаю, оно вам пригодится.

Answer (score 2):

Подпишитесь на событие [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) вашей формы, use the [DrawEllipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse(v=vs.100).aspx) method on the e.Graphics object. Something like this:
Где-нибудь в конструкторе:

```
form1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.form1_Paint);
```

обработчик:

```
private void form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a local version of the graphics object for the PictureBox.
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    // Create location and size of ellipse.
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = 200;
    int height = 100;

    // Draw ellipse to screen.
    g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, x, y, width, height);
}
```

цвета в параметры.
После нажатия на кнопку меняете цвет и дёргаете [Invalidate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate(v=vs.110).aspx) у формы, чтоб перерисовалась.